# Safest way to connect Raspberry Pi to Arduino Uno R3

Tags: serial, i2c, arduino

I am working on a robot using an Arduino Uno R3 and I wanted to have the ability of controlling the Arduino wirelessly, like stopping the Arduino without having to pull the power-plug every time.

I want to know the safest way to connect my Raspberry Pi to the Arduino, without huge risk of voltage going either way badly.

I looked at using i2c and Serial, as per these pages: http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/ & http://blog.oscarliang.net/connect-raspberry-pi-and-arduino-usb-cable/. I have yet to look up USB. The reason that I'm asking this question is that on the i2c post it said that I should look out for the voltage difference:

> **How Does It Work? Is It Safe?**
>
> The Raspberry Pi is running at 3.3 Volts while the Arduino is running
>   at 5 Volts. There are tutorials suggest using a level converter for
>   the I2C communication. This is NOT needed if the Raspberry Pi is
>   running as “master” and the Arduino is running as “slave”.

How can I safely connect the RPi as the master and the Arduino as the slave.

Comment: Just connect via USB. To shut the arduino down, you could just add a (NPN) transistor to one of the GPIO ports that will pull the reset pin of the arduino to ground, keeping the arduino in a 'shutdown' state till the reset line is restored.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Absolute safest would be Bluetooth serial. With a supported USB dongle on the Raspberry Pi and something like a [Bluefruit EZ-Link](http://www.adafruit.com/products/1588) on the Arduino, you could program and control the Arduino from the Raspberry Pi with no physical connection.

Next best would likely be through USB. There is a “standard” protocol ([Firmata](http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page)) for interacting with Arduino and sensors, but it might not be ideal for robotics.

Comment: Hoo! $22, not exactly cheap, but okay! Will look into this!

Comment: Try ebay for cheaper alternatives if cost is a factor

Comment: When you say Bluetooth serial, would this work? https://www.foxytronics.com/products/187-jy-mcu-bluetooth-serial-port-module

Comment: Yes, the JY-MCU one would likely work after a lot of fiddling. The more expensive one I linked to handles all of the complex setup stages. That's worth the price difference to me.

Comment: Okay, great. I like fiddling and this one is cheaper, and the service is great, so I think I will go with this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The short answer to your question, *how* to safely connect the RPi to an Arduino, is indeed given at the first link you posted: http://blog.oscarliang.net/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/. I have used the method given there with great success, and without damaging any components.

But your question suggests that you don't trust that method, and I think the key to trusting it is in understanding *why* it is safe.  This is explained in the paragraph after the one you cited, but perhaps with too much detail.  The key is the lack of a "pull-up" resistor on the 5V Arduino.  Without it, the only voltage supply is from the 3.3V RPi, which fortunately is high enough for the Arduino to recognize.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want to spare your USB port of your Rpi, you can use GPIO Serial to communicate with your Arduino. There is a great [tutorial](http://conoroneill.net/connecting-an-arduino-to-raspberry-pi-for-the-best-of-both-worlds/) of Conor O'Neill for connecting Rpi with a Arduino Pro Mini. The procedure is the same with your Arduino Uno.

All you need is a [LLC](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/11978) (Logic Level Converter) to be able to connect these two devices. As you've already mentioned, these devices run at different voltage levels.